# How do i change a menu image opacity when a menu item is active

Tags: html, css

All menu items have an opacity of 0.4. what i want is to change the opacity of the image to 0.8 onClick. the active image should remain at that opacity even on hover. I am using CSS.Can anyone help in this? i would prefer a CSS solution.

```css
#menu-bar {
  width: 50%;
  height: 99.9%;
  background-color: #1c333a;
  background-size: cover;
  float: left;
}

nav,
nav:before,
nav:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  margin-left: 45%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: transparent;
}

nav ul {
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #7c5eab;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all .4s ease-out;
}

nav ul li a {
  position: relative;
}

#menu-img {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 52px;
  height: auto;
  opacity: .4;
  transition: transform .4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: -webkit-transform .4s ease-in-out;
}

#menu-img:hover {
  opacity: .8;
  width: 83%;
  max-width: 58px;
}

#menu-img .active {
  opacity: .8;
  width: 83%;
  max-width: 58px
}
```

```html
<div id="menu-bar">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-interface-33/80/Home-512.png" id="menu-img" class="active" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-interface-33/80/Home-512.png" id="menu-img" class="active" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-interface-33/80/Home-512.png" id="menu-img" class="active" />
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

here is the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/cernray/703qh8vv/3/

Comment: `onClick` is a javascript event. So if you want something to be done with `onClick` event, you do need Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML code is anvalid, you cannot have multiple images with the same ID. Exchange this to class names.

Use the a:focus pseudo class to assign properties when a link (which surrounds your img) is clicked.

```css
#menu-bar{
 width:50%;
 height:99.9%;
 background-color:#1c333a;
 background-size: cover;
 float: left;
} 
  
nav,nav:before,nav:after {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
nav {
 margin-left: 45%;
 top: 0;
   left: 0;
 background: transparent;
}
nav ul {
 text-align: center;
}
nav ul li {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 position: relative;
   width: 70px;
   height: 70px;
 background-color:#7c5eab;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 transition:all .4s ease-out;
}
nav ul li a { position: relative; 
}

.menu-img{
 width: 80%;
 max-width: 52px;
 height: auto;
 opacity: .4;
 transition: transform .4s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transform:-webkit-transform .4s ease-in-out;
}
.menu-img:hover{
 opacity: .8;
 width: 83%;
 max-width: 58px;
}

a:focus .menu-img  {
  opacity: .1;
 width: 83%;
 max-width: 58px
}
```

```html
<div id="menu-bar">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#" >
             <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-interface-33/80/Home-512.png" class="active menu-img" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li >
         <a href="#" >
             <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-interface-33/80/Home-512.png" class="active menu-img" />
            </a>
           </li>
           <li >
            <a href="#">
               <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-interface-33/80/Home-512.png" class="active menu-img"  />
              </a>
           </li>   
      </ul>
     </nav>
     
  </div>
```

Comment: The problem is that the effect disappears when i click outside the menu items.

Comment: That is what a focus is - when you click on another element, the previous element looses it's focus.
For a persitent change you require to change the class via JS

Comment: would you please provide a working JS code? thanks in advance.